# External database

Tags: 6, database

How can one pull data from an external database on a shared host in Drupal 6

Got date-nodes and a view1 with database1 for mysite.com and need that view1 also on sub.mysite.com running with database2 without the need to import every date-node in database2

Drupal core 6.22
Calendar 6.x-2.4
Date 6.x-2.7
Views 6.x-2.16
Rotor Banner 6.x-2.8

I tried it with Views 3.x but didn't succeed AND Rotor Banner doesn't work with Views 3.x

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the external database setup in your settings.php file?

```
$db_url['default'] = 'mysqli://user:password@localhost/db';
$db_url['external'] = 'mysqli://user:password@localhost/db2';
```

You're not attempting a join or create relationships across the databases (more complicated process still under development) so to set this up you can use the [Table Wizard](http://drupal.org/project/tw) module to connect the two. Install the module, and then navigate to "Content Management -> Table Wizard -> Relationships"; you should be able to connect to tables in the 'external' database and use their fields in creating views.